# How to find and list of months between 2 given months using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find and list of the months between two given months.

**Input data**

```
Month1    Month2     Month_list
Mar2020   Dec2020
Nov2020   Jan2021
Sep2020   Feb2021
Jun2020   Dec2020
Oct2020   Mar2021
```

**Expected output**

```
Month1    Month2     Month_list

Mar2020   Sep2020    Mar2020,Apr2020,May2020,Jun2020,Jul2020,Aug2020,Sep2020
Nov2020   Jan2021    Nov2020,Dec2020,Jan2021
Sep2020   Feb2021    Sep2020,Oct2020,Nov2020,Dec2020,Jan2021,Feb2021
Oct2020   Dec2020    Oct2020,Nov2020,Dec2020
Dec2020   Mar2021    Dec2020,Jan2021,Feb2021,Mar2021
```

Code snippet I have been using:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import OrderedDict
dates = [df.Month1, df.Month2]
start, end = [datetime.strptime(_, "%Y-%m-%d") for _ in dates]
```

How to find the list of months and year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apply -

```
def get_date_list(x):
    return ",".join(
        item.strftime("%b %Y")
        for item in pd.date_range(x['Month1'], x['Month2'], freq="MS")
    )
    
df['Month_list'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_date_list(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: It gives Error if Month1 and Month2 column is blank, Error: ValueError: Neither start nor end can be NaT

Answer (score 2):

Use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html).

I am assuming you have already parsed your dates since you haven't mentioned it in your question. Here is a partial solution to your problem:

```py
>>> start = pd.to_datetime("Mar 2021")
>>> end = pd.to_datetime("Sep 2021")
>>> [d.strftime("%b %Y") for d in pd.date_range(start, end, freq="MS")]
['Mar 2021',
 'Apr 2021',
 'May 2021',
 'Jun 2021',
 'Jul 2021',
 'Aug 2021',
 'Sep 2021']
```